# Sign a JAR automatically when building from Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, build, self-signed, jar-signing

I want to know if Netbeans has some option or setting that will allow me to automatically sign a jar as part of the build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `-post-jar` ant target, it may be convenient to read the [<signjar>](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/signjar.html) password from a file, e.g. *~/.keyconf*. Give the file user-only access: e.g. `400` or `600`.

```
<loadfile srcfile="${user.home}/.keyconf" property="keyconf"/>
<signjar alias="..." storepass="${keyconf}">
    ...
</signjar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [the maven plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jarsigner-plugin/index.html) for that. Netbeans is able to open and create maven files out-of-the-box.

If you need signing for jnlp you could look into [this](http://karussell.wordpress.com/2009/05/05/maven-and-webstart-jnlp/) and [that](http://karussell.wordpress.com/2009/05/16/further-with-maven-and-webstart-jnlp/) explanation, which works fine in my TimeFinder project [see the pom.xml](http://timefinder.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/timefinder/trunk/timefinder-core/pom.xml?revision=810&view=markup).