# Morena signed Jars causing problems with my Jars

Tags: java, security, jar, applet, digital-signature

Im using the Morena API's in order to make use of scanners thorough Java. However the Morena jar's have been signed using a different key then the rest of my project. This is causing problems when I'm trying to run my applet and gives the following runtime exception:

```
"Jar resources in JNLP file are not signed by the same certificate"
```

I am using netbeans for my project, so how can I force Morena to use my signature rather then the one it came with?

JNLP Files that are auto generated by netbeans:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
<information>
    <title>ArFile</title>
    <vendor>Matthew Pigram</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://www.allcarecomputerservices.com"/>
    <description>ArFile is designed to allow users to effectively manage documents through a convenient cloud storage facility</description>
    <description kind="short">ArFile</description>

</information>
<update check="always"/>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
`<j2se java-vm-args="-Djava.security.policy=applet.policy" version="1.6+"/>
<jar href="ArFile.jar" main="true"/>    
<jar href="lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jdom.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/security-1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/emcesu.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-io-2.3-javadoc.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-io-2.3-sources.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-io-2.3-test-sources.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-io-2.3-tests.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-io-2.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jodconverter-core-3.0-beta-4.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/juh-3.2.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jurt-3.2.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/ridl-3.2.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/unoil-3.2.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/mail.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/morena.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/morena_windows.jar"/>
</resources>
    <applet-desc height="604" main-class="com.allcare.arfile.ArFileJApplet" name="ArFile" width="756">     
    </applet-desc>
</jnlp>`
```

And also this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="${jnlp.codebase.value}">
    <information>
        <title>jnlpcomponent1</title>
        <vendor>JARSIGNI</vendor>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <jar href="lib/morena.jar" download="eager"/>
        <jar href="lib/morena_windows.jar" download="eager"/>
    </resources>
    <component-desc/>
</jnlp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way Java Web Start ensures that the jars that the client downloads are not compromised with. It is a security feature.

What you can do is try signing the Morena jar using your certificate rather than the default one.

Using `keytool` and `jarsigner` you can sign the jars.

EDIT : Beginning with Java Web Start 1.5.0, you can multiply sign the jar, adding code signing certificates over another existing certificate chain

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/faq.html#221

So you can sign the Morena jar with your signature and that will resolve the issue.

Comment: How can I do this in Netbeans?

Comment: You can use Ant for this . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520031/sign-a-jar-automatically-when-building-from-netbeans

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to solve this problem:

1. Move the Morena API Jars into a JWS extension.  This would be the best way to go, since it can claim it's own level of privileges, and be reused in other apps.
2. Strip the digital signatures from the Morena Jars and sign them with your own certificate.

Comment: If I show you the contents of my current JNLP file could you show me what the JWS extension would look like?

Comment: I like option 1, but would that be an additional jnlp file to maintain? For 2, do we need to strip the signatures? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/faq.html#221 says we can use multiple signatures.

Comment: @Mathew check this out http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kirillcool/archive/2005/05/signing_jars_fo.html

Comment: @Matthew You seem to be on the right track with the extension JNLP seen in your last edit.  It needs to be referenced in the `resources` section of the main JNLP.  Something like `<extension href='morena.jnlp' />`

Comment: I try that but my applet just freezes up during execution, I do do not even use the morena libraries in code yet so I assume that this referencing isnt enough

Comment: @AjayGeorge your solution was correct and resolved the issues I was having, I just signed those jars and then ran my applet successfully, so now they have multiple signatures :D

write this as an answer and ill give you the tick